# How to represent an integral equation over a pulse duration of a circuit in latex?

Tags: integral

I would like to represent the following integral equation using latex. The square pulse in the integral denotes a square pulse of a clock. Can anyone suggest me how I can use the square pulse here? That is the only problem I am having while writing the equation.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The package `ifsym` provides `\PulseHigh`

Comment: You might also consider `\int I_{tot}(t) p(t) dt`, where `p(t)` is your pulse profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ifsym`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{moresize} 
\usepackage[electronic]{ifsym} 

\begin{document}

\[ E_{\text{dyn}} = V_{\text{DD}} \underset{\textbf{\ssmall\PulseHigh}}{\int} I_{\text{tot}(t)\,\mathrm dt-P_{\text{stat}\cdot T} )} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, probabily there are any errors for your code in relation to the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using TikZ, here is an ad-hoc solution. Otherwise, you can use the `ifsym` package as pointed out by @egreg, but, the documentation is in German.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pulse}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt,scale=.3]
\draw (0,0)--++(.3,0)--++(0,.5)--++(.5,0)--++(0,-.5)--++(.3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{equation}
E_\text{dyn}=V_\text{DD}\int\limits_{\pulse} I_\text{tot}(t)-P_\text{stat}\cdot T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ifsym` package (but it only provides bitmap fonts) or draw yourself the symbol. Equation (1) below shows the hand-made symbol, equation (2) uses `ifsym`. If you go for method (1), loading `ifsym` is unnecessary, but `pict2e` is.

One should note that the symbols provided by `ifsym` are for *text*, so if used in math they have to be surrounded by `\text`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage[electronic]{ifsym}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\pulse}{%
  \text{%
    \settoheight{\unitlength}{T}%
    \begin{picture}(2.2,1)
    \roundcap
    \polyline(0.1,0)(0.6,0)(0.6,1)(1.6,1)(1.6,0)(2.1,0)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_{\mathrm{dyn}} =
V_{\mathrm{DD}}\int\limits_{\pulse} I_{\mathrm{tot}}(t)\,dt
- P_{\mathrm{stat}}\cdot T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E_{\mathrm{dyn}} =
V_{\mathrm{DD}}\int\limits_{\text{\PulseHigh}} I_{\mathrm{tot}}(t)\,dt
- P_{\mathrm{stat}}\cdot T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]